# TypeError: 'ModelBase' object does not support indexing.

Tags: django, sqlite, model

I created the models.py file and when I try to execute the 'makemigrations' command, I get the following error:

```
    return bool(self.related_name) and self.related_name[-1] == '+'
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object does not support indexing
```

I tried to find a forum reply, but the topics mainly concern the error that appears from the views.py file. In my situations, this file has not been created yet.

Any help will be appreciated, also about the more transparent code in the database.

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models


#additives
class TestUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Trade(models.Model):
    all_trade_here = models.TextField()

class ImageGallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

class SocialMediaLinks(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()

# Option for premium user
class Prem_PhotoGallery(models.Model):
    name_photo_gallery = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image_gallery = models.ForeignKey(ImageGallery,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Prem_PDF(models.Model):
    name_pdf = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField()

class Prem_YouTube(models.Model):
    name_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()

class Prem_VilmVeo(models.Model):
    name_vilmveo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()

class Prem_Audio(models.Model):
    name_audio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()

class Prem_Website(models.Model):
    name_website = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()

class Prem_SocialMedia(models.Model):
    name_social_button_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    links = models.ForeignKey(SocialMediaLinks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Prem_GoogleMaps(models.Model):
    name_google_maps = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()

# element write by user
class Person(models.Model):
    #basic information, all write user
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    photo = models.FileField()
    small_photo = models.FileField()
    description = models.TextField()
    recommended_by = models.ForeignKey(TestUser,
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_projects = models.ManyToManyField(Prem_PhotoGallery,
                                         Prem_PDF,
                                         Prem_YouTube,
                                         Prem_VilmVeo,
                                         Prem_Audio,
                                         Prem_Website,
                                         Prem_SocialMedia,
                                         Prem_GoogleMaps,
                                         blank=True)
    keywords = models.TextField()
    trade = models.ManyToManyField(Trade)

    #premium
    premium_accounts = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #location
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    #data joined
    time_create_account = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ManyToManyField` configuration for `my_projects` is not correct. A [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) takes a single class as it's first positional argument. It can also accept other optional arguments such as `related_name`.

You have passed multiple classes as arguments. `ManyToManyField` would thus assume that these other classes correspond to the values for the optional arguments, causing the error you're seeing.

You would need to separate `my_projects` into separate `ManyToManyField`s:

```
my_photogalleries = models.ManyToManyField(Prem_PhotoGallery)
my_pdfs = models.ManyToManyField(Prem_PDF)
... etc ...
```